# react-native : Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, gradle, build, react-native

After upgrading from `0.17` to `0.19` I'm getting this error every time I'm trying to `build` the `application` using ( `react-native run-android` ). I've tried downgrading back to 0.17 but it didn't help and the problem is the same. I've also searched the web but couldn't find anything similar to my problem . I guess the problem is with `gradle` not the `react-native` itself but I don't know how to solve it ?!

Here is the error :

```
Starting JS server...
Starting the packager in a new window is not supported on Windows yet.
Please start it manually using 'react-native start'.
We believe the best Windows support will come from a community of people
using React Native on Windows on a daily basis.
Would you be up for sending a pull request?
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat install
Debug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:0.19.+.
     Required by:
         sess:app:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:0.19.+.
         > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
            > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/co
m/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/r
eact-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused

* Try:
Run with —stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with —info or —debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 48.737 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem some days ago . It seems that you have a problem with connection , a slow one, or the site is blocked by your ISP (for any reason) or filtered by you country (like china). Try using a Proxy and try again, it worked for me .

By the way the problem is not with react-native, its with gradle. And the community will include these jar files with react-native package in v0.21 which is coming this week and your problem with jcenter will be solved I hope .